# change id attr's value using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a table whose data is fetched from the database, and this table's each td's id is also dynamically unique **( td's id value is equal to database's table value )**. In each td, when anyone double click on it, an input field is appeared, when the user edits an input field, I have made an Ajax call (using onblur), and update this td's field in the database. which will be worked I guess, Now I want to change that td's id value, which will come from database (Ajax call).

for example::

My table code ::

```
<td id="2*Name>Engr._C.F._Zaman" class=" "> Engr. C.F. Zaman  </td>
```

this td's **id** is generated from **database**, where first **2 is id of the table's id**, after **(*)** is the **db table's column name [Name]** and after **(>)** is the **value of that column's whose id is 2**

when anyone click on this td, he/she will get an input field just like as given below::

```
 <td id="2*Name>Engr._C.F._Zaman" class=" ">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sabbir" value="Engr._C.F._Zaman" name="Name" onblur="AjaxChange('2', 'Name', 'Engr._C.F._Zaman', '2*Name>Engr._C.F._Zaman');">
 </td>
```

this is generated using jquery **onclick** event.

Now if any change of above input field, **AjaxChange** is called. and my AjaxChange code is ::

```
function AjaxChange( id,  Attr, tdValue, td ) {  
   $.ajax({
      url: "ajax_call.php",  // this is just update the db 
      type: "POST",
      data: { table: "life", id=id, name=Attr, value=tdValue },  // 
      dataType: "html",
      done: function(data) {
        // first I want to change the id of td, which value will be data
        // td's id format is id*Attr>data

        // next show data in the td with out input field
        // <td id="id*Attr>data"> data </td>
      }
   });
 }
```

Now How can I change this td's **id** attribute?

Comment: Just curious, Why are you using meta characters in `id="2*Name>Engr._C.F._Zaman"`?

Comment: so that I extract 2, Name, Engr._C.F._Zaman, any better idea?

Comment: I would suggest you to use data-* attributes

Comment: I don't get it. The id is just an attribute, have you tried setting it with $(this).attr('id','myNewId')? [this if inside the click() handler]

Comment: @sabbir, I have given an alternative solution, if you wish you can implement that

Answer (score 2):

Solution to immediate problem.

```
<td id="2*Name>Engr._C.F._Zaman" class=" ">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sabbir" 
        value="Engr._C.F._Zaman" 
        name="Name" 
        onblur="AjaxChange('2', 'Name', 'Engr._C.F._Zaman', '2*Name>Engr._C.F._Zaman', this);">
</td>
```

Script function

```
function AjaxChange( id,  Attr, tdValue, td, element ) {  
   $.ajax({
      url: "ajax_call.php",  // this is just update the db 
      type: "POST",
      data: { table: "life", id=id, name=Attr, value=tdValue },  // 
      dataType: "html",
      done: function(data) {
        //Set ID
        $(element).closest("td").prop('id', YourNewID)
      }
   });
}
```

---

However, I would strongly recommend you to refactor your code and use **data-*** attribute. Heres example

*HTML*

```
<td class="" data-value="2*Name>Engr._C.F._Zaman" data-id="2" data-attr="Name" data-name="Engr._C.F._Zaman" >
    <input type="text" class="form-control name-txt" 
        value="Engr._C.F._Zaman" 
        name="Name">
</td>
```

*JavaScript*

```
$('.name-txt').on('blur', function(){
    var self = $(this);
    var cell = self.closest("td");
    var id = cell.data('id');
    var Attr= cell.data('Attr');
    var name= cell.data('name');
    var tdValue = cell.data('value');

    $.ajax({
      url: "ajax_call.php",  // this is just update the db 
      type: "POST",
      data: { table: "life", id=id, name=Attr, value=tdValue },  // 
      dataType: "html",
      done: function(data) {
        //Update values using
        cell.data('id', YourNewID)
      }
   });
})
```

Comment: I strongly second this too!

Comment: I second this aswell, the id is something you use to identify an unique element, you rarely change this attribute. Using the data-* attribute instead not only makes it easier to find your unique element (since you can id it) but also is compatible with all standards.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you meant using javascript/jquery, meaning the easiest way to reach the id would be using jqueries "attr"-function.

Now the question is what selector you should use, I guess in this case that your input fields id ("sabbir") is sufficient enough. You will have to decide this on your own.

```
$("#sabbir").closest("td").attr("id", yourNewId);
```

As answer to the other question in your comment:

```
$("#"+yourNewId).html(data);
```

Should work to replace the tds HTML.

Comment: This is not a very hard problem, the problem is to determine how to find your td. I suspect "#sabbir" is just a temporary id, you must figure out a way to find your td. Perhaps you can do it by tracking the dom from the table?

Comment: you read my mind, My only problem is to change the id's value of td, how can I figure out to find this td, plz help me

Comment: Do not change the ID and use a data-value attribute instead. :) There is a solution above here which is really good.

Comment: Thanks for your advice @Undrium, I already do as you said, And It works awesome,

Answer (score 1):

your's ID `2*Name>Engr._C.F._Zaman` which come from **Database**, is bad. Because **special char** is not always give result what you want, you should avoid this special char. You can use `data-*` to store your **Database** information then you don't have to change your **ID** every time.